# Can I change the Pandoc typesetting engine to XeTeX or LuaTex?

Tags: latex, pandoc

I'm trying to use the font Arial in my document and convert from markdown to latex. I included the following in my latex template:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

This works and changes the font to Arial when I use it normally, but when I use Pandoc to convert to PDF, I get the error:

```
Error producing PDF.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.28 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

It says that the package requires XeTeX or LuaTex. I've tried many things to change the font to Arial, but nothing so far has worked.

I use OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To use LuaTex when creating a pdf with Pandoc:**

```
pandoc test.txt --pdf-engine=lualatex -o test.pdf
```

Apply accordingly for XeTex:

```
pandoc test.txt --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

**From the Pandoc [Manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers):**

> **--pdf-engine=pdflatex|lualatex|xelatex|wkhtmltopdf|weasyprint|prince|context|pdfroff**
>
> Use the specified engine when producing PDF output. The default is
> pdflatex. If the engine is not in your PATH, the full path of the
> engine may be specified here.

Have a look at the [Demo Section](https://pandoc.org/demos.html) of the manual - most use cases are covered there.

Comment: Thanks for telling me! But now I'm getting an error `File ucharcat.sty not found.` I searched through the template.latex file and it isn't there.

Comment: This means that `ucharcat.sty` is either not installed or is in a place where Latex is not looking for it. As this is a totally different problem: search on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for `sty not found`. If this doesn't help to solve the problem, you may ask a new question there.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did no longer work for me.  Apparently we can simply replace the symlink.

```bash
 $ cd /usr/bin
 $ mv pdflatex pdflatex_ && cp pdftex.exe pdflatex.exe
 $ pandoc -s foo.md -o foo.pdf
```

That worked better but now another error popped:

```bash
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `lmodern.sty' not found.
```

Installing *texlive-collection-fontsrecommended* made it go away and a valid PDF was rendered.